# Who established that $K_e = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon _m}$?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism

*Coulomb's Law* states that :
$$F_e = K_e\dfrac{q_1q_2}{r^2}$$
where $q_1$, $q_2$ are magnitudes of the two point charges, $r$ is the distance between them and $K_e$ is 
*Coulomb's Constant* (aka *Dielectric Constant*). In my Physics textbook, it's mentioned that $K_e$ can also be written as $\dfrac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_m}$, where $\varepsilon_m$ is ther permittivity of a medium $m$ but no details about its establishing or derivation are given.

So, I'd like to know who established this (I think it was Gauss, though), thanks!

PS : If it was Gauss, was it established by using Gauss's Law?

Comment: $4\pi r^2$ is the surface area of a sphere of radius $r$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not that a particular person established this relation. This relation is a result of the historical development of the idea of assigning units or rather dimensionality to charge $q$. According to the Wikipedia article on [Vacuum permittivity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity#Historical_origin_of_the_parameter_%CE%B50):

> The experiments of Coulomb and others showed that the force $F$ between
>   two equal point-like "amounts" of electricity, situated a distance $r$
>   apart in free space, should be given by a formula that has the form
>
> $F=k_{\text{e}}{\frac {Q^{2}}{r^{2}}}$
>
> where $Q$ is a quantity that represents the amount of electricity
>   present at each of the two points, and $k_e$ is the Coulomb constant. If
>   one is starting with no constraints, then the value of $k_{\text{e}}$ may be
>   chosen arbitrarily. For each different choice of $k_e$ there is a
>   different "interpretation" of $Q$: to avoid confusion, each different
>   "interpretation" has to be allocated a distinctive name and symbol.
>
> In one of the systems of equations and units agreed in the late 19th
>   century, called the "centimetre–gram–second electrostatic system of
>   units" (the cgs esu system), the constant $k_e$ was taken equal to 1, and
>   a quantity now called "gaussian electric charge" $q_s$ was defined by the
>   resulting equation
>
> $F={\frac {{q_{\text{s}}}^{2}}{r^{2}}}$

Thus, charge was expressed in esu, a derived CGS unit with dimensions as
$[M]^{1/2}[L]^{3/2}[T]^{-1}$.

> The idea subsequently developed that it would be better, in situations
>   of spherical geometry, to include a factor $4π$ in equations like
>   Coulomb's law, and write it in the form:
>
> $F=k'_{\text{e}}{\frac {{q'_{\text{s}}}^{2}}{4\pi r^{2}}}$
>
> The quantities $q'_s$ and $k'_e$ are not the same as those in the older convention. Putting $k_e = 1$ generates a unit of electricity of different size, but it still has the same dimensions as the cgs esu system.

This is the [Lorentz–Heaviside](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz%E2%80%93Heaviside_units) system of units. Lorentz–Heaviside units, unlike Gaussian units, are rationalised, meaning that there are no factors of $4π$ appearing explicitly in Maxwell's equations.

> The next step was to treat the quantity representing "amount of
>   electricity" as a fundamental quantity in its own right, denoted by
>   the symbol $q$, and to write Coulomb's Law in its modern form:
>
> $F={\frac {1}{4\pi \varepsilon _{0}}}{\frac{q^{2}}{r^{2}}}$

This is the SI system with Ampere as a fundamental unit for electric current. Coulomb is the unit of charge with one Coulomb being equal to one Ampere-second. This makes the dimensionality of charge as $[I]^{1}[T]^{1}$.